# how to describe jax-rs web service like wsdl to a third party client?

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, wadl

I am recently started working on Java , JAX-RS Jersey API . I am given a job to develop JAX-RS web services . I started reading online articles about JAX-WS and JAX-RS.

In JAX-WS webservice can be described by WSDL file , so lets say I build web-service and then I pass it on to the client where she will understand what to request (object types to pass in request) and what response object she will get back.

I JAX-RS i see, there is WADL is document but which is "optional" , so if client doesn't have the WADL and have just JAX-RS URI how she will understand expected request and response objects?

Some one down voted with no reason, at-least please provide reason or some answer or correct me.

Answer (score 0):

You may check Swagger (http://www.swagger.io). It can generate interactive HTML documentation page based on your annotated methods in a code. It automatically detects HTTP methods, method parameters and prepares forms for testing.